# Literature recommendation: Algebraic Quantum Field Theory

Tags: reference-request, mathematical-physics, book-recommendation, quantum-field-theory

I’m starting out doing a PhD in Algebraic Quantum Field Theory and I’m struggling to find any good books on the subject that focus on the material from a mathematical perspective.

The algebraic aspect is of paramount importance here. Things to be included are about Minkowski space, Lorentz transformation, Poincare group etc.

Comment: Hi, you should use also the reference-request tag because you're seeking for references in you question and not about a specific topic of QFT.

Answer (score 0):

I think the canonical reference would still today be "Local Quantum Physics" by Rudolf Haag.